# Azure API Management developer portal customization

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management developer portal, could I add some fields in the Template like, I would like to add "Company Name" field in Sign-Up template. I have tried it but can't see the Company Name Model name in Sign-Up template Models.

Comment: Are you talking about Azure API Management?

Comment: Yes, juunas! I have to do it in Azure web API management

Comment: I think I am late in the party but 
You might have to use Azure AD B2C and have to add those fields in AD and from there you might be able to add extra fields while Signup..